# What is best way to copy report several times given a parameter?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have a report that is pretty simple.. it just autofills information into shipping labels which can then be printed.  The user wants to be able to print X number of labels.  I just want the report to be copied X number of times, but can't really think of the best way to do that.  I would want it to copy below however many times.

Let me know if you need more context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this (unfortunately, rather manually) by created a tablix and inserting 25 rows.  I changed the visibility expression per line and just dropped the original report as a subreport in each tablix row.  Worked well, but on a much larger scale, automation would be necessary.